# IOS - Keep UIView on top of UITableView on scroll

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have a UITableView with a UIView on top. I want the UIView to stick to the top as the tableView cells scroll over it.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    if (self.tableView.contentOffset.y > 0) {
        CGRect newframe = self.publicTopView.frame;
        newframe.origin.y = -self.tableView.contentOffset.y;
        self.publicTopView.frame = newframe;
        NSLog(@"After: %f", self.publicTopView.frame.origin.y);
    }
}
```

Comment: ... and what goes wrong when you use that code?

Comment: You say "UIView on top of the UITableView", but contradict that by saying "as tableview cells scroll over it". So what is on top of what?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set your table view header view to the view you want on top.

Add this code to you viewDidLoad

```
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.publicTopView
```

Comment: Thanks @Omar Al-Shammary its woking fine

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain what you're trying to accomplish, but I have a guess at what is wrong.  As you scroll your `contentOffset` will continue to change and let's say your `tableView` has a content size height of 1500, then your `contentOffset` will eventually be larger than the height of your view controllers view.  Now see that you are putting that `contentOffset` into the `origin.y` of your `publicTopView`.  So your `publicTopView` could possibly be moving too much, even offscreen depending on how large your tableview's content size is.